# Can't use latest compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion without version conflicts if using Google Play Services

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am using the Google Nearby Services library.

I have the following Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rstudio.vedantroy.swarm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Non-default Dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

In the above file, the support library is outdated, thus forcing me to compile my app and target it against SDK 26:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

The problem is, if I update my support library to `28.0.0`, then I will get the "support libraries must be the exact same version" error, because I believe the Google Play Nearby Services library uses an older version of the support library.

Is there any way to fix this, or am I stuck compiling my app against API 26?

Comment: Use a `resolutionStrategy` to force Gradle to use the newer support library for Nearby's transitive dependencies. Or, add your own `implementation` lines for those transitive dependencies, requesting the newer version. BTW, isn't Google discontinuing Nearby?

Comment: Google is discontinuing Android Nearby Notifications, but it seems like they are supporting Android Nearby Messages: "https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html". Also, will forcing Gradle to use the newer support library lead to any runtime crashes because `play-services-nearby` depends on an older version of the support library?

Comment: Ah, OK, I keep forgetting there are multiple things branded "Nearby". "will forcing Gradle to use the newer support library lead to any runtime crashes because play-services-nearby depends on an older version of the support library?" -- possibly. Usually this isn't a problem, but we can't rule it out.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to update your `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` to 28.

After that, you can solve this by using:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

This will force each support library dependency to use exact same version `28.0.0`.